# Adding Foreign Key to Django Import Export

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-import-export

I am trying to import data from a csv using Django_Import Export. I saw other SO posts but they are not helping. Below are the models

Models.py

```
class TblSubject(amdl.AagamBaseModel):
    subject_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    standard = models.ForeignKey('TblStandard', models.DO_NOTHING)
    remembrance_credit = models.IntegerField(default=40)
    applied_knowledge_credit = models.IntegerField(default=30)
    understanding_credit = models.IntegerField(default=30)
    subject_credit = models.IntegerField(default=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tblsubject'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.subject_name}'


class SubjectChapter(amdl.AagamBaseModel):
    subject_chapter_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey('TblSubject', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chapter_id = models.IntegerField()
    chapter_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    remembrance_credit = models.IntegerField()
    applied_knowledge_credit = models.IntegerField()
    understanding_credit = models.IntegerField()
    chapter_credit = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'subject_chapter'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.chapter_id} {self.chapter_name} : {self.subject}'
```

Here is the admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export import resources, fields
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget
from .models import SubjectChapter, TblSubject
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin


class SubjectChapterResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = SubjectChapter
        import_id_fields = ('subject_chapter_id',)
        subject = fields.Field(
            column_name='subject_name',
            attribute='subject_name',
            widget=ForeignKeyWidget(TblSubject, 'subject_id'))


class SubjectChapterAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = SubjectChapterResource


admin.site.register(SubjectChapter, SubjectChapterAdmin)
```

And i am getting this below error

[image]

I am inserting data for SUBJECTCHAPTER from csv where the SUBJECT column is a foreign key from TBLSUBJECT and it contains the name of the TBLSUBJECT.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
class SubjectChapterResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = SubjectChapter
        import_id_fields = ('subject_chapter_id',)
        subject = fields.Field(
            column_name='subject_name',
            attribute='subject_name',
            widget=ForeignKeyWidget(TblSubject, 'subject_name'))
```

From `subject_id` to `subject_name`

Comment: It is still showing the same error: "Field 'subject_id' expected a number but got 'Mathematics 001'."

Comment: fakeMake's answer should have resolved this.  Please review the [documentation](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.ForeignKeyWidget), which explains how to import using a related field other than PK

Comment: @MatthewHegarty I do understand that his answer should have solved, as I went through the documentation and other SO posts before asking here. I tried that same before myself. Also thinking I might have made mistakes I copied his answer and pasted and ran but couldn't solve my problem. I doubt that the issue is somewhere due to my negligence of learning django and implementing primary auto keys for each table. But now I cannot change it. As django_import_export still used the `id` field for primary keys I guess.

Comment: Understood.  If you can step through with a debugger you should be able to solve it pretty quick.  Please post back with more information if you think we can help further.